# Parse argument with a number and an optional letter

Tags: macros, parsing

How to define a macro which takes a string made by number and an ***optional*** letter and then branches on the basis on the letter?
Since this is an extension of an existing package, it is preferable not to use any package or LaTeX3; furthermore, since the syntax is not defined yet, you could implement the answer with the letter following or preceding the number, with any separator you want (none is better).

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myparse#1{...} % or \newcommand{\myparse}[1]{...}

% Suppose the letter has to be after the number with no separator,
% and the command branches on letters "b", "m", "e" to represent
% the beginning, middle or end of a year.

\begin{document}
\myparse{2004b} % Should print "Beginning of 2004"
\myparse{2005}  % Should print "2005"
\myparse{2005m} % Should print "2005" too
\myparse{2006e} % Should print "End of 2006"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why complicating it too much? `xparse` and or `xstring` are quite stable packages which can be used basically everywhere?

Comment: We might need some more context: for example, how are you defining a 'number' here, do you need an expandable solution, _etc._

Comment: @JosephWright "Number": sequence of digits (we only deal with positive integers). The number needs to be handled by `pgf`, but there is no imaginable need to use macros as arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\myparse#1{\afterassignment\xmyparse\@tempcnta#1\relax}
\def\xmyparse#1\relax{\csname myparsexx#1\endcsname}
\def\myparsexxb{Beginning of \the\@tempcnta}
\def\myparsexx{\the\@tempcnta}
\def\myparsexxm{\the\@tempcnta}
\def\myparsexxe{End of \the\@tempcnta}
\makeatother

% Suppose the letter has to be after the number with no separator,
% and the command branches on letters "b", "m", "e" to represent
% the beginning, middle or end of a year.

\begin{document}
\myparse{2004b} % Should print "Beginning of 2004"

\myparse{2005}  % Should print "2005"

\myparse{2005m} % Should print "2005" too

\myparse{2006e} % Should print "End of 2006"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Superb! I really need to read the TeXbook... The definition of `\myparse` assigns the number to `\@tempcnta` and gobbles it, then the non-number part of `#1` is passed to `\xmyparse`, right?

Comment: @Astrinus: Right. The really cute idiom, IMHO, is the `b`, `e`, `m` dispatch via the macro identifiers.

Comment: @Astrinus yes, the `\relax` is added as a terminator so after the number assignment xmyparse skoops up everything up to `\relax` which is nothing or a letter (hopefully:-)

Answer (score 7):

You can be liberal in your syntax, allowing the key before or after the year (actually, the key can appear anywhere and multiple times; the last letter appearing will set the behavior).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myparse}{m}
 {
  \astrinus_myparse:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_astrinus_myparse_year_tl
\tl_new:N \l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \astrinus_myparse:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_astrinus_myparse_year_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \astrinus_add_token:n { ##1 } }
  \astrinus_print:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \astrinus_add_token:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { 0123456789 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_astrinus_myparse_year_tl { #1 }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \astrinus_print:
 {
  \str_case:Vn \l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl
   {
    {b}{Beginning~of~}
    {e}{End~of~}
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_astrinus_myparse_year_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myparse{2004b} % Should print "Beginning of 2004"

\myparse{b2004} % Should print "Beginning of 2004"

\myparse{2005}  % Should print "2005"

\myparse{2005m} % Should print "2005" too

\myparse{m2005} % Should print "2005" too

\myparse{2006e} % Should print "End of 2006"

\myparse{e2006} % Should print "End of 2006"

\end{document}
```

The input is scanned token by token; digits are accumulated in `\l_astrinus_myparse_year_tl`, while a letter sets `\l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl`. Finally we match `\l_astrinus_myparse_key_tl` with the possible cases and do the appropriate action.

[image]

Comment: This is also superb, but it loads `xparse`... and I'm not the package maintainer, who absolutely doesn't want to make it depends on any further package.

Comment: @Astrinus, tell him that if `xparse` is used, his package will be future-proof.

Answer (score 5):

An approach using e-TeX to give an expandable solution. The idea is to loop over the input, testing if each token is a digit or not. If it is, simply keep it, while if it's not then assume we've reached the end of the number and trigger a begin/middle/end phase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Just so \meaning looks right when printed

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myparse[1]{%
  \myparse@auxi#1\q@tail\q@stop{}%
}
\newcommand*\myparse@auxi[1]{%
  \ifx\q@tail#1%
    \expandafter\myparse@end
  \fi
  \if\number\numexpr0#1-0#1\relax0%
    \expandafter\myparse@auxii
  \else
    \expandafter\myparse@auxiii
  \fi
    #1%
}
\newcommand*\myparse@auxii{}
\def\myparse@auxii#1#2\q@stop#3{%
  \myparse@auxi#2\q@stop{#3#1}%
}
\newcommand*\myparse@auxiii{}
\def\myparse@auxiii#1#2\q@stop{%
  \csname myparse@aux@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*\myparse@aux@b[1]{Beginning of #1}
\newcommand*\myparse@aux@m[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\myparse@aux@e[1]{End of #1}

\newcommand*\myparse@end{}
\def\myparse@end#1\q@stop#2{#2}

\def\q@tail{\q@tail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myparse{2004b} % Should print "Beginning of 2004"

\myparse{2005}  % Should print "2005"

\myparse{2005m} % Should print "2005" too

\myparse{2006e} % Should print "End of 2006"

\edef\test{\myparse{2006e}}\meaning\test
\end{document}
```

The solution is in this sense similar to that by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232153) except that the digit detection is done in macros rather than using a TeX primitive assignment.

Comment: I'm assuming 'well-behaved' input, no spaces, no macros, _etc._ but the question seems to suggest this is OK.

Comment: I've accepted David Carlisle answer, because is shorter and simpler and, for the time being, it is enough. But this is beautiful (e)TeX too! Should the need arise, I'll remember of this answer (upvoted).